# C# Imap search command with special characters like á,é

Tags: c#, imap

I'm working on an imap client search function.

I use this command: **UID SEARCH FROM *PÉTER***

When I run this command i get the following error:
*Error in IMAP command UID SEARCH: 8bit data in atom*

I get this error when my pattern string(for example PÉTER) contains accentuated character.

What is the solution? What sholud I do?

Edit:
I try with UTF-8 encoded string (**UID SEARCH FROM PÉTER**), it runs without error, but it doesn't give back any result. 
I check the test email account, and there are many mails with this sender.

Comment: Try to use UTF-8 encode.

Comment: Can you give me more details?

Comment: Looks likely to be dependent on the implementation of the IMAP server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In IMAP you need to send 8-bit data as string literals.

Literal syntax:
{byte_count} CRLF number-of-bytes

Example search:
cmdTag SEARCH charset UTF-8 subject {4} CRLF test CRLF