# IMAP search command with UTF-8 charset in C#

Tags: search, encoding, utf-8, imap, 8-bit

[C# Imap search command with special characters like á,é](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7426661/c-sharp-imap-search-command-with-special-characters-like-a-e)

I am trying to implement the logic mentioned in the above post in C# to achieve non-ascii based searches in gmail. After logging in successfully to imap.gmail.com I am having the following transaction with the server:

```
(C -> S) Encoding.Default.GetBytes("A4 UID SEARCH CHARSET UTF-8 TEXT {4}\r\n");
(C <- S) "+ go ahead\r\n"
(C -> S) Encoding.Default.GetBytes("αβγδ\r\n");
(C <- S) "* SEARCH 72\r\nA2 OK SEARCH completed (Success)"
```

However the email denoted by the response of the server is completely irrelevant to the search term I provided. This only happens when using non-ascii characters in the keywords and I believe I have something wrong with the encoding.

I have also tried using `Encoding.Ascii` but then I get search results that are even more off target.

What is the proper way to send the string literal: `"αβγδ\r\n"`

Answer (score 4):

For the search term, you are using a so-called *literal*. The length of the literal has to be specified in octets. That's not the case in your example. The string "αβγδ" encoded in UTF-8 consists of more than four octets.

So, you should encode the search term before sending the length to the server.

I don't know much about C#. I make an example with Python:

```
search_term = 'Grüße'
encoded_search_term = search_term.encode('UTF-8')
length = str(len(encoded_search_term)).encode('ascii')

send(b'. UID SEARCH CHARSET UTF-8 TEXT {' + length + b'}\r\n')
read_until(br'^\+ .*$')

send(encoded_search_term + b'\r\n')
read_until(br'^\. OK .*$')
```

With this code, the search command returns the UIDs of the emails with the text "Grüße":

```
C: b'. UID SEARCH CHARSET UTF-8 TEXT {7}\r\n'
S: b'+ Ready for literal data\r\n'
C: b'Gr\xc3\xbc\xc3\x9fe\r\n'
S: b'* SEARCH 1 3 4\r\n'
S: b'. OK UID SEARCH completed\r\n'
```

If I use the length in characters (`len(search_term)`) instead of the encoded length in octets (`len(encoded_search_term)`), the IMAP server reports an error:

```
C: b'. UID SEARCH CHARSET UTF-8 TEXT {5}\r\n'
S: b'+ Ready for literal data\r\n'
C: b'Gr\xc3\xbc\xc3\x9fe\r\n'
S: b'. BAD expected end of data instead of "\\237e"\r\n'
```

Note, I didn't use Gmail for my tests.

Comment: I stand corrected. I will test this as soon as I have some time.


If I understand correctly the two things I've done wrong are that #1 I havent performed the convertion of the search term to bytes in UTF8 (instead of Encoding.Default) and #2 I should place the number of decoded bytes to where {4} is at right now.


Thanks again in advance and feel free to correct me if I am misinterpreting your answer.

Comment: search_term = 'Grüße'
encoded_search_term = search_term.encode('UTF-8')
length = str(len(encoded_search_term)).encode('ascii')

This part is trully illuminating. I could have never figured it out on my own. Thanks a billion m8. I wish I had enough points to upvote you. As I said I will test this as soon as I have some time. Cheers.