# Unable to sort using Mail::IMAPClient

Tags: perl, imapclient

Yesterday I was trying to sort the emails coming from imap using the Mail::IMAPClient library doing the following:

```
my $imap = Mail::IMAPClient->new(
#my imap settings
);
#folder selection
my @messages = $imap->sort('(REVERSE ARRIVAL) UTF-8 ALL');
```

But I got:

> 4 BAD Error in IMAP command UID SORT: Invalid sort list argument
>   (0.000 + 0.000 secs). at /var/www/localhost/htdocs/user/mail.pl line
>   93.: /var/www/localhost/htdocs/user/mail.pl

I was several hours trying to resolve this issue until I found the answer. (below)

Comment: Just a note, you should [avoid indirect object syntax](https://perldoc.pl/perlobj#Indirect-Object-Syntax).

Comment: Thanks, I will avoid it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I should point I was inspired from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24507633/c-sharp-imap-sort-command-with-special-characters) question from came the wrong idea of put everything as a single argument.

The correct answer was:

```
my @messages = $imap->sort('(REVERSE ARRIVAL)', 'UTF-8', 'ALL');
```

I should separe sort pattern from charset and charset from search pattern as the different arguments they are.
Now my code is working.